# Start and end indices of continuous True intervals

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have the following Pandas Series:

```
s = pd.Series([False, True, True, False, True, True, True, False, True])
```

How can I get a list of tuples that each tuple represents the start and end index of continuous True intervals. For the above snippet the expected result would be:

```
[(1, 2), (4, 6), (8, 8)]
```

Comment: I agree, it is somehow similar to that question; but the first step is to convert the series to indices as you initially answered by doing `trues = s[s].index.values`. And from there you can use that answer.

Comment: Use `start_stop(s, trigger_val=True, len_thresh=0)` from linked dup Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
t=s[s].index.to_series()
t.groupby(t.diff().ne(1).cumsum()).agg(['first','last']).apply(tuple,1).tolist()
Out[257]: [(1, 2), (4, 6), (8, 8)]
```